# How would I best express this in English?

Tags: academic-writing

I'm new to English writing and, unfortunately, I cannot even find words to describe the problem properly (I guess there would be a special name for this issue).
I wrote a sentence *"[...] the assessment of alpha-diversity only requires the distinction between, but not the identification of species"* but I am not sure whether this is clear and correct or it would be preferable to wrap the "what it is not"-part (I want to highlight what it is not about, however just slightly ;D) in em dashes. I'm also not sure about the necessity of the "but". But then, should lots of dashes even be used in scientific writing?
So, what's the most appropriate version?

1. [...] requires the distinction between, but not the identification of species
2. [...] requires the distinction between—but not the identification of—species
3. [...] requires the distinction between—not the identification of—species

Comment: Hi Manuel! I think both #2 and #3 are grammatically correct, but #2 is the most pleasing in terms of sounding like natural English. I would personally go with that one. Alternatively, if you'd like a different flow, you could say: "the assessment of alpha-diversity requires the distinction between species, but not necessarily the identification of said species." This clarifies the grammatical structure of the sentence a bit more in my opinion, but again, it is all a personal choice. I hope that helps!

Comment: This appears to be 3 questions - all are good, but I feel that the main question is better suited to [ell.se] or [English.se], since it is about [grammar and syntax rules](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-we-allow-grammar-questions-on-here) (specifically [subordinate/dependent  clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause)), as also the secondary question regarding "but".  The tertiary question, about the use of em-dash in scientific writing, most certainly *is* on topic here though, and probably deserves its own post :)

Comment: Who migrated that from SE Writing seems to be dodging the issue.

Other than personal choice of style, there is no useful difference in those three examples.

If there were a problem, would that not more likely be using "… requires the…" rather than "… a distinction…"?

Come to that, what would be wrong with "… only requires distinction between, not identification of species"?

I suggest this is wholly about style, and clearly does belong to SE Writing